# How to bind TextBlock.Text in DataGridCell template using ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I want to have `DataGridCell` with text and image.
Currently, my code looks like that

XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="myDataGrid" CellStyle="{StaticResource myCellStyle}" />
```

Style:

```
<Style x:Key="myCellStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                    <Image/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

C#:

```
myDataGrid.ItemsSource = myDataTable.DefaultView;
```

The **question** is:
How to bind text to a `TextBlock` using `ItemsSource`?

Comment: Who own's `ItemsSource`? Where does it reside?

Comment: My mistake. I forgot about DataGrid name property which is set in my code. Please take a look on my example now.

Comment: Have you tried `<TextBlock Text="{Binding ColumnName}"/>` with ColumnName being the text column from your DataTable that you want to display?

Comment: It doesn't work. I didn't mention about that, but I'm generating DataTable dynamically and my DataGrid almost always have different columns and rows. That's why i can't set style for specific column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must do couple of things to fix it

First, set 'AutoGenerateColumns' to true

```
<DataGrid CellStyle="{StaticResource myCellStyle}" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
```

Next in your cell style

```
<Style x:Key="myCellStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
                        Path=Content.Text}"/>
                    <Image/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Wojtman Has anyone taken this further to get the image working or to bind the text to other properties?

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that `myDataTable.DefaultView` is a list of some objects(class instances).

So when the grid gets its `ItemsSource` set, it will then will present *each row* **with one** of the items from the list. So the binding to be specified will be a property/properties on the class.

So taking from your example template, if it is bound to a hypothetical list of person classes with `FirstName` and `LastName` on the class instance, one could set the template to bind to use those properties for each row like this:

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
       <Image/>
  </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, myDataTable is made from strings (not custom objects with properties) and that's the problem. I have no idea how bind single string to my TextBlock.

Comment: Create a Data Transfer Object class (DTO) with the appropriate properties and take the datatable data and new up a list of the DTOs from it. Program the DTO class's constructor to get specific columns from the datatable and load target properties from that. Then bind as shown but have the grid use the new `List<{DTOClass}`>.

Comment: I made as u said and now if style is implemented then grid do not show data but if style is not implemented then every cell have value like "myNamespace.myClass". So maybe there is something wrong with this property in my style <Setter Property="Template"> ?